# Defining a distribution for survival::survreg()

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I try to fit a survreg model using the gamma distribution.

Following `?survreg.distributions` I defined my custom distribution like this:

```
gamma <- list(name = 'gamma',
          parms = c(2,2),
          init = function(x, weights, ...){
            c(median(x), mad(x))
          },
          density = function(x, parms){
            shape <- parms[1]
            scale <- parms[2]
            cbind(pgamma(x, shape=shape, scale=scale),
                  1-pgamma(x, shape=shape, scale=scale),
                  dgamma(x, shape=shape, scale=scale),
                  (shape-1)/x - 1/scale,
                  (shape-1)*(shape-2)/x^2 - 2*(shape-1)/(x*scale) + 1/scale^2)
          },
          quantile = function(p, parms) {
            qgamma(p, shape=parms[1], scale=parms[2])
          },
          deviance = function(...) stop('deviance residuals not defined')
)
```

However I can't get it to run:

```
require(survival)
survreg(Surv(log(time), status) ~ ph.ecog + sex, lung, dist=gamma)
#Error in coxph.wtest(t(x) %*% (wt * x), c((wt * eta + weights * deriv$dg) %*%  : 
#  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 3)
```

The error comes from some C-Code but I think it is generated much earlier...

Any hints/suggestions/alternatives to survreg?

Comment: I see two possibilities. You could be throwing the error with the stop call or if you were passing negative numbers to log() you would expect NaN's so who know unless you offer the data?

Comment: @DWin: Thanks, I'll try to debug the C-Code and check the inputs. My example is reproducible, the lung data comes with the survival package. log(time) is fine, all positive.

Comment: Doing some searching in Markmail I find that survreg is intended to be used with distributions that have a location-scale parameters, and that gamma is not in that family. http://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help++survreg+gamma+therneau#query:list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help%20%20survreg%20gamma%20therneau+page:3+mid:t2pcdpq6p2pimpvl+state:results

Comment: After some more search i found the `flexsurv` package - see my answer below.

Comment: I did some debugging; it looks like the problem is that, inside `survreg.fit`, a local function `derfun` is used to compute the derivatives of the density, and this returns several `-Inf`s for the first derivative and therefore `NaN`s for the second. This could turn out to have nothing to do with location-scale distributions. For instance, the exponential distribution is coded into `survreg.distributions` (albeit as a transformation), but it is in fact a special case of the gamma distribution.

Comment: @ssdecontrol The exponential distribution is a location-scale distribution...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the `flexsurv` package which implements a generalized gamma distribution.

For Weibull distribution the estimates from `survreg` and `flexsurvreg` are similar (but note the different parametrization:

```
require(survival)
summary(survreg(Surv(log(time), status) ~ ph.ecog + sex, data = lung, dist='weibull'))

Call:
survreg(formula = Surv(log(time), status) ~ ph.ecog + sex, data = lung, 
    dist = "weibull")
              Value Std. Error      z         p
(Intercept)  1.7504     0.0364  48.13  0.00e+00
ph.ecog     -0.0660     0.0158  -4.17  3.10e-05
sex          0.0763     0.0237   3.22  1.27e-03
Log(scale)  -1.9670     0.0639 -30.77 6.36e-208

Scale= 0.14 

Weibull distribution
Loglik(model)= -270.5   Loglik(intercept only)= -284.3
    Chisq= 27.62 on 2 degrees of freedom, p= 1e-06 
Number of Newton-Raphson Iterations: 6 
n=227 (1 observation deleted due to missingness)


require(flexsurv)
flexsurvreg(Surv(log(time), status) ~ ph.ecog + sex, data = lung, dist='weibull')

Call:
flexsurvreg(formula = Surv(log(time), status) ~ ph.ecog + sex,     data = lung, dist = "weibull")

Maximum likelihood estimates: 
            est    L95%    U95%
shape    7.1500  6.3100  8.1000
scale    5.7600  5.3600  6.1800
ph.ecog -0.0660 -0.0970 -0.0349
sex      0.0763  0.0299  0.1230

N = 227,  Events: 164,  Censored: 63
Total time at risk: 1232.1
Log-likelihood = -270.5, df = 4
AIC = 549
```

With flexsurvreg we can fit a generalized gamma distribution to this data:

```
flexsurvreg(Surv(log(time), status) ~ ph.ecog + sex, data = lung, dist='gengamma')

Call:
flexsurvreg(formula = Surv(log(time), status) ~ ph.ecog + sex,     data = lung, dist = "gengamma")

Maximum likelihood estimates: 
            est    L95%    U95%
mu       1.7800  1.7100  1.8600
sigma    0.1180  0.0971  0.1440
Q        1.4600  1.0200  1.9100
ph.ecog -0.0559 -0.0853 -0.0266
sex      0.0621  0.0178  0.1060

N = 227,  Events: 164,  Censored: 63
Total time at risk: 1232.1
Log-likelihood = -267.57, df = 5
AIC = 545.15
```

The loglogistic distribution is (in contrast to `survreg`) not build in, but can be easily custumized (see examples of `flexsurvreg`).

I haven't tested it too much, but `flexsurv` seems to be a good alternative to `survival`.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer to a `survreg` question.